# Jenkins is unable to access SVN repository

Tags: jenkins, svn, continuous-integration, svnkit

I am using tortoise SVN for version control , I am saving path to my repository that have no credentials or any user , still Jenkins is showing error.

I am using Jenkins on my local machine

[image: Jenkins LOG]

[image: local repository]

Help me solve my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems SVNKit used by Jenkins doesn't support FSFS format 7 repositories. You have two options to workaround this:

1. Create repository in Subversion 1.8 compatible format using `svnadmin create --compatible-version=1.8`.
2. Configure svnserve and access this repository over `svn://` protocol [recommended]

Comment: Hi, Thanx for the answer ,  can you please elaborate how to configure svn server and access it over svn:// protocol and what's diff between file and svn protocol?

Comment: @Keshav I think it's offtopic for this question, but svnserver configuration described in detail in SVNBook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html